# encoding byte data to base64 string in vb6 and decoding base64 string to byte data in java is not same

Tags: java, vb6, base64

I am encoding byte data to base64 string in vb6 by the following code :

```
Dim Fingerdata As String
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
objNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = g_Template
Fingerdata = objNode.Text

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing
```

I am decoding this base64 string to byte data in java by the following code :

```
String templateString = request.getParameter("temp"); 
byte[] fingerbytes = Base64.decodeBase64(templateString);
```

But surprisingly , I have noticed that initially byte data and the byte data which is got after decoding base64 data is not same . How can I make sure that the two byte data are same ? Please help me .

Comment: So, why did you tag this with c#?  There's no c# here.

Comment: Thanks . The question is edited.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.  To get identical results you have to encode identical data.  Most likely one is using UTF-8 character encoding and the other UTF-16LE encoding. Your `nodeTypedValue` expects a Byte array and you feed it `g_Template` which is what, a UTF-16LE String?  If so those bytes are coerced to a Byte array. No idea what you might be doing in Java.

Comment: The decleration of  g_Template is ReDim g_Template(dLen) As Byte . So  g_Template  is a Byte array .

Comment: Which one is  UTF-8 character encoding and which one is UTF-16LE encoding ?