# How to pass byte data from C# to Servlet in Java

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, servlets

I am trying to pass byte data from C# to java servlet . The code is as follows :

```
byte[] data = futronicApp.getFingerVerificationData(name,SampleModel);
String passingData = "cust_no=" + name + "&serial=" + serial + "&temp=" + data; 
jsonparser = new JSONParser("http://10.11.201.31:8085/FingerEnrollVerify/EnrolledFingerVerify", "POST", passingData );
```

The definition of JSONParser class is as follows :

```
public JSONParser(string url)
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        }
        public JSONParser(string url, string method) : this(url)
        {
            if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = method;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
            }
        }
        public JSONParser(string url, string method, string data) : this(url, method)
        {
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = data;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
        }
```

Then in java servlet I am trying to get this byte data . The code is as follows :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        System.out.println("Finger Enroll Verify"); 

        String customerNumber = request.getParameter("cust_no");
        System.out.println("cust_no is "+customerNumber); 


        String serial = request.getParameter("serial");
        int serial_no = Integer.parseInt(serial);
        System.out.println("Serial_no is "+serial_no);  

        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        byte[] fingerbytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        System.out.println("fingerbytes length: "+fingerbytes.length);
}
```

But I am getting "fingerbytes length: 0" . Why ? How can I pass byte data from C# to Java servlet ? Please help me .

Comment: suppose you have to encode the byte array.

Comment: I have tried to encode the byte array to base64 string . In java I have got byte array by  decoding the base64 string . But Initially he byte array and after decoding byte array is not equal . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116642/encoding-byte-data-to-base64-string-in-vb6-and-decoding-base64-string-to-byte-da

Answer (score 0):

bytes cannot be treated like chars like this.
Effectively the reason this doesn't work is because you have a string with different types of data in it.

Normally you would "stream" bytes to a server rather than "stringify" them as the string representation of a byte is usually a number.

luckily though there is a built in function to allow this ...

```
String passingData = "cust_no=" + name + "&serial=" + serial + "&temp=" + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
```

this will get you your whole post as a string,

then on the java end you will have to split the string from the byte array and to the same in reverse by using somehting like ....

```
var dataString = postedString.split("&temp=")[1];
var data = dataString.getBytes();
```

Comment: I am using this code in java end : String template = request.getParameter("temp");
byte[] array=template.getBytes(); But this does not give me whole byte array .

Comment: surely it should be ... byte[] array = request.getParameter("temp").getBytes();

Answer (score 0):

data is an array of Bytes. So, generate a string from this array and send it to servlet.

```
byte[] data = futronicApp.getFingerVerificationData(name,SampleModel);
String passingData = "cust_no=" + name + "&serial=" + serial + "&temp=" + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
```

And in the servlet, receive temp from post params to a string and do getBytes() to get a byte array. Code is not tested. Just wanted to share the idea.